# Can't get basic Ruby/Sinatra app working with Heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku

All my files can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/Integralist/Passage (just in case you need to see what I'm working with).

I'm new to Heroku and I tried following the instructions for getting a Sinatra app uploaded but it just doesn't run and when I visit the app URL I get a generic "Application Error" message.

My set-up process has been as follows:

- `heroku login`
- `heroku create --stack cedar`

Create `config.ru` file and add the content...

```
require 'app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Create a Gemfile file (no file extension) and add the content...

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra', '1.3.2'
gem 'thin', '1.3.1'
```

Open the Terminal (I'm running Mac OS X) and execute: `bundle install` which seems to generate a duplicate Gemfile but this time with a .lock file extension? This other Gemfile now has the following content...

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    daemons (1.1.8)
    eventmachine (0.12.10)
    rack (1.4.1)
    rack-protection (1.2.0)
      rack
    sinatra (1.3.2)
      rack (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.6)
      rack-protection (~> 1.2)
      tilt (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.3)
    thin (1.3.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    tilt (1.3.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  sinatra (= 1.3.2)
  thin (= 1.3.1)
```

Then I create a `Procfile` (no file extension) and add the content: `web: bundle exec ruby app.rb -p $PORT` (app.rb is obviously the name of my main application file).

I then stage/commit/push my files using Git to the relevant Heroku repo.

But if I run `heroku ps` I get...

```
=== web: `bundle exec ruby app.rb -p`
web.1: crashed for 1m
```

And then if I run `heroku logs` I get...

```
2012-06-09T18:35:41+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-06-09T18:36:37+00:00 heroku[api]: Add LANG, PATH, RACK_ENV, GEM_PATH config by email@domain.com
2012-06-09T18:36:37+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by email@domain.com
2012-06-09T18:36:38+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by email@domain.com
2012-06-09T18:36:38+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy e26921b by email@domain.com
2012-06-09T18:36:38+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-06-09T18:36:38+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-06-09T18:36:40+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec ruby app.rb -p`
2012-06-09T18:36:41+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/main.rb:15:in `<class:Application>': missing argument: -p (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
2012-06-09T18:36:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/main.rb:4:in `<module:Sinatra>'
2012-06-09T18:36:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/main.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2012-06-09T18:36:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra.rb:5:in `require'
2012-06-09T18:36:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-06-09T18:36:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from app.rb:12:in `require'
2012-06-09T18:36:41+00:00 app[web.1]:   from app.rb:12:in `<main>'
2012-06-09T18:36:42+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-06-09T18:36:42+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-06-09T18:36:42+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2012-06-09T18:36:42+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-06-09T18:36:44+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec ruby app.rb -p`
2012-06-09T18:36:45+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/main.rb:15:in `<class:Application>': missing argument: -p (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
2012-06-09T18:36:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/main.rb:4:in `<module:Sinatra>'
2012-06-09T18:36:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/main.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2012-06-09T18:36:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra.rb:5:in `require'
2012-06-09T18:36:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-06-09T18:36:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from app.rb:12:in `require'
2012-06-09T18:36:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from app.rb:12:in `<main>'
2012-06-09T18:36:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-06-09T18:36:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-06-09T18:42:09+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET furious-wind-9309.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-06-09T18:42:09+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET furious-wind-9309.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-06-09T18:42:38+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET furious-wind-9309.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-06-09T18:42:39+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET furious-wind-9309.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Can someone explain what the problem is and how I can fix it please.

Thanks.

Comment: What's in your `app.rb`? Since you are using a `Procfile`, your `config.ru` isn't initializing the server, `app.rb` is (from the `ruby app.rb` command).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/main.rb:15:in `<class:Application>': missing argument: -p (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
```

That is the error it is giving you in the stack trace. When it is running `bundle exec ruby app.rb -p` there is no argument given for `-p`. You need something like `bundle exec ruby app.rb -p 3000` (to run on port 3000). Perhaps the global variable $PORT is not getting defined?

EDIT

Though form [heroku's docs on the Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile):

```
You can reference other environment variables populated by Heroku, most usefully the $PORT variable, in the command.
```

Try doing a `raise $PORT.inspect` and then pushing to heroku. It will crash, but hopefully with a better picture of what it is trying to do.

Comment: With Heroku, you should definitely be using $PORT, since the dynamic nature of Heroku means that it needs to pass a port for the app to use, and does not have statically available ports.

Comment: Looking at the [Procfile in question](https://github.com/Integralist/Passage/blob/9ea1914ac1edf39a9fa08af7ffa2332b1b453a44/Procfile), `$PORT` is actually missing altogether (despite what the question says).

Comment: By George, @matt is right! That pretty much narrows down the issue.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Although I was sure I added $PORT it obviously got deleted somehow?